# Как проверить работоспособность брокера RabbitMQ?

Tags: python-3.x, django, rabbitmq, celery

Установил RabbitMQ. Как проверить его работоспособность? Использовал в купе с celery. Но сейчас отказывается работать. Пишет, что удаленный сервер отклонил ответ. Сначала все было почти нормально, задачи ставились в очередь, но не выполнялись. После переустановки celery все изменилось.